Есть ли в данном предложении однородные члены?
Немного в замешательстве пребываю...
Речь идёт о предложении "Мне стало жарко, и я пошёл домой". (Предложение взято из головы, я хотел изолировать для себя данный кейс)
Сайт автоматической проверки синтаксиса отмечает, что в данном предложении есть однородные члены, в чём я сомневаюсь. Как однородные отмечены "Стало" и "пошёл", но это ведь нелогично?
Как ко мне (исходя из моего скромного знания), мы имеем дело с двумя предложениями, первое из которых просто не имеет явно выраженного подлежащего, но есть сказуемое "стало", и оно ведь не может относиться к "Я" во втором предложении?
Или я чего-то не понимаю D:

Мой вариант разбора

Объяснение
Сложносочинённое (союз "и") предложение.
Стало жарко (кому?) мне.
Пошёл (кто?) я.
Пошёл (куда?) домой.

Слово "стало" в данном случае выступает в качестве глагола-связки (попробуйте убрать слово "жарко" из предложения).
Есть ли в данном предложении однородные члены?
Предложение не осложнено однородными членами.
